# Deriving the Maximum Range of a Particle With A Constant Force Using Geometric Algebra

Tags: vectors, clifford-algebras, kinematics, geometric-algebras, projectile-motion

I am learning Geometric Algebra by reading *New Foundations for Classical Mechanics*, by David Hestenes. Chapter 3-2 studies the motion of a particle with constant gravitational force and on page 129 the maximum range of the particle is derived. There are two parts I am stumped on for deriving equation (2.12) which is as follows:

$$
\begin{equation}
r_{max} =\frac{2v_{0}^{2}}{g}\frac{1}{| \hat{\mathrm{r}} -\hat{\mathrm{g}}| ^{2}} =\frac{v_{0}^{2}}{g}\frac{1}{1-\hat{\mathrm{g}} \cdotp \hat{\mathrm{r}}}
\end{equation}
$$

Equation (2.8) is the equation for range, $r$, which is:

$$
\begin{equation}
r=\frac{2(\hat{\mathrm{g}} \land \mathrm{v}_0) \cdot (\mathrm{v}_0 \land \hat{\mathrm{r}})}{|\mathrm{g} \land \hat{\mathrm{r}} |^2}
\end{equation}
$$

The numerator of (2.8) is "maximized" to get equation (2.10). To maximize, uses a vector identity to resolve that $2(\hat{\mathrm{g}} \land \mathrm{v}_0) \cdot (\mathrm{v}_0 \land \hat{\mathrm{r}})=\mathrm{v}_0^{2}[\hat{\mathrm{g}} \cdot \hat{\mathrm{r}} - \hat{\mathrm{g}} \cdot (\mathrm{v}_0 \hat{\mathrm{r}} \mathrm{v}_0)]$. This I understand.

By maximizing, he finds that the numerator has a maximum value when $\hat{\mathrm{g}} \cdot (\hat{\mathrm{v}_0} \hat{\mathrm{r}} \hat{\mathrm{v}_0}) = 1$, then concluded that $-\hat{\mathrm{g}} \hat{\mathrm{v}_0} = \hat{\mathrm{v}_0} \hat{\mathrm{r}}$, which says that $\hat{\mathrm{v}_0}$ can be expressed as a function of $\hat{\mathrm{v}_0}$ and $\hat{\mathrm{g}}$ and writes it as (2.11):
$$
\hat{\mathrm{v}}_0=\frac{\hat{\mathrm{r}}-\hat{\mathrm{g}}}{|\hat{\mathrm{r}}-\hat{\mathrm{g}}|}
$$

**My Confusion**

Then, (2.11) is substituted into (2.8) and gets equation (2.12). I have attempted this multiple times to get the same result but do not get an equation that looks anything like (2.12). I feel as though I am missing some key geometric algebra identities that'll lead the solution. I would appreciate assistance, thank you.

**EDIT**

Here is the pages from the book!

[Page 128](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmP3z.png)

[Page 129, Part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTXNa.png)

[Page 129, Part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WMeB.png)

Comment: Is it possible to post the entire derivation? Many of us do not have that book. This is normally a straight forward derivation in the plane without using vectors.

Comment: @JohnDouma Heh, sorry about that, I was not aware that you could put images here (wish I knew that before spending 30 minutes struggling with LaTeX...) I added the pages! Hope it helps. Also, I'm aware of the straight-forward nature of the problem without using vectors, I am just concerned with how to derive this in the language of geometric algebra.